# Why was the question I link below, deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926649/what-is-the-value-of-k/2926665

Why was this question deleted?

You can just provide a very simple reason. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think that your edit to the question was appropriate.  You should not be editing questions to put words into the mouths of other users.  While I agree that the original asker should have shown their work (or, better yet, provided more context in general), the suggestion to do so should be made in the form of a **comment** below the question, and not in an edit.

Comment: Ok. I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for closure is given below the question you've linked:

"This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

The asker failed to take that advice seriously; they had a chance to improve the post, but they failed to do so.  But the short version is precisely given by @Hurkyl.

Comment: It wasn't my question, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Max0815  Apologies for attributing the question to you.  I've edited my post to address the asker in the third person.

Answer (score 6):

Because that post is treating MSE as a homework mill.